# Maps Implementation to avoid loop

Tags: apex, trigger, map

How will I use maps to avoid inner for loop.As a best practice I have to utilise maps.

```
Map<Id, list<Lead>> existingLeads;

    public static void sendEmail(existingLeads, List<Lead> leadFromWebsite) {

        string body = 'Id, Name , Email, Mobile\n';

        for (Lead l : leadFromWebsite) {
            if (existingLeads.containskey(l.id)) {
                for (Lead l : existingleads.values()) {

                    string recordString = l.id + ',' + l.Name + ',' + l.Email + ',' + l.MobilePhone + '\n';
                    body = body + recordString;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of 2nd for loop use map to get values. Lead leadrecord =existingleads.get(l.id);

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is unclear from your code and your question actual requirements. plz elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using inner loop by using this method. What it does is, in the for loop, the existingLeads Map finds the lead ID for the first time, so it stores the id and the lead record it found in the map (as mentioned in the else condition). After that, when it again finds the same ID, but a new lead record, using get(l.id).add(l), the Map stores the new lead record it found for the already existing ID.

```java
Map<Id, list<Lead>> existingLeads;

public static void sendEmail(existingLeads, List<Lead> leadFromWebsite) {
    string body = 'Id, Name , Email, Mobile\n';

    for (Lead l : leadFromWebsite) {
        if (existingLeads.containskey(l.id)) {
            existingLeads.get(l.id).add(l)
        }
        else {
            existingLeads.put(l.id, new list<lead> {l});
        }
    }   
                    
    for (Lead l : existingleads.values()) {
        string recordString = l.id + ',' + l.Name + ',' + l.Email + ',' + l.MobilePhone + '\n';
        body = body + recordString;
    }
}
```